# Joomla performance issue CPU/Memory 100% usage

Tags: php, mysql, performance, joomla

I have a joomla site which is eating up a lots of CPU resources. It has a JA TELINE theme. To narrow down the issue i've installed a cleaned joomla site and tried to see if it eats up CPU but it doesn't. But the moment i connect my new joomla to older site's DB,  CPU is hitting the roof. New site has only required modules and template from JA Teline. I can't figure out whats causing the CPU n Memory usage to go 100%. This is happening even if there are 1-2 visitors on the website.

CPU is a 2 core processor and server has 2GB dedicated ram even though it is hosted on a shared hosting environment.

I have SSH access to my hosting. If i run TOP command i see about 10-15 threads for php and each consuming about 20-50% CPU.

Comment: 2GB is tiny these days.  Since you tagged it with mysql, please provide the values in my.cnf; they may need to be decreased.  Also, what other programs are running?  Joomla and what else?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at malware infections , Because your server might be infected with malware spam bot or any malware that consumes your resources.

Also I suggest you disabling each plugin one by one to check how memory is decreasing.

Also you can run top -c to see what uses most of your resources.

I hope this helps to better understand what is going on.